# How can I read a csv file stored in a hdfs file system at a server in spark using intellij at my local system?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, server, hdfs

I am using intellij to write spark code. And, I want to access files stored in hdfs file system at a server. How can I access the hdfs file in the Scala spark code so that it can be loaded as a dataframe??

Answer (score 0):

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("CSV_Import_Example")
           .config("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname","XXX")
           .config("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address","XXX:8032")
           .config("spark.yarn.access.namenodes", "hdfs://XXXX:8020,hdfs://XXXX:8020")
           .config("spark.yarn.stagingDir", "hdfs://XXXX:8020/user/hduser/")
           .getOrCreate()
```

The entry point into all functionality in Spark is the SparkSession class.

```
val sourceDF = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("hdfs://192.168.1.1:8020/user/cloudera/example_csvfile.csv")
```

hdfs://192.168.1.1:8020 here is accessing the HDFS Cluster & 8020 port is related to namenode.

Comment: I have already tried this. But it gives me an error while connecting...
18/09/12 16:15:46 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 10.10.1.15/10.10.1.15:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); maxRetries=45

Comment: @AnandNautiyal can you please try as per the updated answer and let us know.Thanks

Comment: @prasaanna kumar - Can you please elaborate what should go in each of the config settings. Thanks.